# ScrollableLabel won't scroll

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So as the title says my ScrollableLabel won't actually scroll (the text does display though). I used Sentdex's code as a guide on how to do it and I don't know how I messed up. Sorry if it's a stupid question.

```
class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView): #http://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Scrollable-Label & user sentdex on youtube
        text = StringProperty("")
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

            self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y = None)
            self.add_widget(self.layout)

            self.content = Label(size_hint_y=None, markup=True)

            self.scroll_to_point = Label()

            self.layout.add_widget(self.content)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.scroll_to_point)

        def update_content(self, new_text):
            self.content.text = new_text

            self.layout.height = self.content.texture_size[1]
            self.content.height = self.content.texture_size[1]
            self.content.text_size = (self.content.width, None)

            self.layout.height = self.content.texture_size[1]
            self.content.height = self.content.texture_size[1]

            self.scroll_to(self.scroll_to_point)
```

I was going to try and use kivy language because it seems much simpler but I'd rather do it like this as that's how everything else is (this is for a school project). Thanks for all the help and sorry if the answer is obvious or stupid.

Comment: Probably you're missing some bindings, i.e. the sizes aren't being updated correctly when the texture_size changes. It's hard to tell since the example is incomplete. Maybe start with the kv version, then try to move it to python bit by bit so you can tell when it breaks to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ScrollView demands every widget inside of it to have 'size_hint_y=None', so try to add it to 'self.scroll_to_point'.